# Drupal commerce WPS , if user not go back to the site after paypal payment?

Tags: commerce, payment-gateways

this is the problem.
The payment used in my site is WPS (With Paypal Business account) so user switch from my site to Paypal site to pay order in cart.

BUT

If User close paypal site after paypal message "Payment complete" and NOT go back in site, the status order stay on "Checkout: Complete". Drupal Commerce has no way of knowing that payment is complete so not send order email and decrease stock.

Is there a way to get around this problem?

I work with drupal commerce kickstart 2 (+ stock module)

Ty for your reply :)

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing a similar problem - no confirmation emails etc.

Apparently what was causing the problem for me was that I had created a custom Rule that fired "When an ordered is first paid in full"  and updated the order status to "Completed." This custom Rule triggered after the user used PayPal WPS to complete payment. I did this to avoid the confusion of having the default status "Pending" after the the PayPal payment was successful.

For some reason, having this custom Rule there prevented all the Rules that use the trigger "Completing the checkout process" to trigger (these default rules include all the notification emails among other things).

See this posting here for a few cases of other people who ran into this problem: https://drupalcommerce.org/discussions/1150/resolved-completing-checkout-process-not-firing

This issue was resolved (in my case) by just getting rid of the custom Rule.

I'm wondering if this is causing the problem for you too.

Answer (score 0):

Usually payment processing companies display a message that the customer should not close the window and wait for him/her to be redirected to the merchant site. Paypal should display this in your case. Please ask them to do it, every other payment processing company does it.

Comment: Yes paypal display this message but often user close paypal (or browser) after paypal succesful message. User often not wait redirect to back in the commerce site. The problem is this. If not come back order status not change so not decrease stock and not send email confirmation. (rules send that after order completition)

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing doesn't sound correct to me. PayPal Payments Standard does display a link back to your store, but it isn't required for a customer to click it for any processing to happen for the payment on the Drupal side. Additionally, PayPal really doesn't do much to encourage a customer to click that link - I'd be at least half of customers won't be coming back by your shop after submitting payment unless they're different than mine. : )

What sounds fishy, though, is that your orders remain in "Checkout: Complete". Technically, they should be remaining in "Checkout: Payment", because that's the status they're in when the user redirects to PayPal. However, the IPN must be coming through and triggering some order status change, which is followed by the IPN listener simulating moving the order to the next page, "Checkout: Complete." You need to look into what rules you have operating on when a payment is received in full for an order, because the IPN triggers that whether the customers comes back to the site or not. You are probably changing an order status and it is getting set back somehow.

Comment: Yes, sorry my fault the status remain in "Checkout: Payment", the problem is that: User pay with paypal and no back in the site to complete order (close paypal site). Status remain in "Checkout: Payment" so no confirm order email was send and no stock decrease action was fired. How to solve that?

Comment: Your site needs to be accessible to IPNs. It sounds like it isn't.

Comment: But there is some configuration paypal side? Like url callback or something like that?

Comment: No configuration necessary. We submit the notify_url in the redirect to PayPal, so that's where it sends the IPN regardless of whatever IPN URL you configure in your account.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem. I'm using drupal-commerce but not kickstart. Most of the time, Paypal WPS is working as expected. Though, Sometimes I receive a payment from a customer but the order does not move to "checkout complete". The surprizing part is that when I look to the recorded carts in the admin part ("/admin/commerce/orders/carts"), selecting the corresponding cart, looking to the "Payment" tab of that cart, the payment has been recorded in the database with the result message "The payment has completed.".

Shortly speaking, I have a cart with valid payment in my database but the order is not completed and the stock does not decrease.

Have you checked if the payment is registered in the corresponding cart ?
Any idea about what is happening ?

Comment: This seems to solve the issue : 
http://drupal.org/node/1130166#comment-4813116

Comment: also here some help 
https://www.drupal.org/node/2111633